# Получить значение элемента XML

Tags: xml, php

Здравствуйте. Пытался сам разобраться, да чего-то у меня не выходит.

В общем, дело следующее. 
С чужого сервера в ответ на мои запросы приходит XML - [PASTEBIN](http://pastebin.com/ZEWAtWua)

Пытаюсь получить доступ к элементам `<achiev id = 1>INT</achiev>` и к элементам блока `<playerTalents>`.

Пробовал через SimpleXML, строго действуя документации:

```
<?php
$xml = file_get_contents($url);

$stat = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($stat->data->user->id as $id {
    switch((string) $achieve['id']) { // Получение атрибутов элемента по индексу
    case '1':
        $dmg = $id;
        break;

    }
}
?>
```

Но чего-то ерунда какая-то получается, постоянно возвращается 0.

Так вот, вопрос, как мне все-таки подобраться к нужному мне элементу?

Comment: Приведите пример получаемого файла и что должно из него потом получить на стороне PHP

Comment: @chernomyrdin - ссылку на пример получаемого XML я дал. Да и что нужно и из каких элементов получить, тоже указал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу такой вариант (преобразование данных в массив):

```
function objectsIntoArray($arrObjData, $arrSkipIndices = array())
 {
     $arrData = array();
     // if input is object, convert into array
     if (is_object($arrObjData)) {
         $arrObjData = get_object_vars($arrObjData);
     }

     if (is_array($arrObjData)) {
         foreach ($arrObjData as $index => $value) {
             if (is_object($value) || is_array($value)) {
                 $value = objectsIntoArray($value, $arrSkipIndices); // recursive call
             }
             if (in_array($index, $arrSkipIndices)) {
                 continue;
             }
             $arrData[$index] = $value;
         }
     }
     return $arrData;
 }

$xmlStr = file_get_contents($xmlUrl);     //получили данные
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlStr); //распарсили
$arrXml = objectsIntoArray($xmlObj);      //преобразовали в массив

$arrXml['data']['user']['collections'][0] - доступ к данным.
```

Вообще, если непонятно, как в данный момент хранятся данные, выведите их с помощью `print_r()` или `var_dump()`. Это даст возможность посмотреть, какие индексы использует в текущий момент конкретный массив, и как его лучше вывести.

Comment: @Magos спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. 

Проблема в том, что постоянно возвращает кучу NULL, как бы я не правил под структуру документа. 

Сейчас попробую Ваш вариант.

Comment: @Magos возвращает Null .

Comment: Изучил вывод сам и подробно. Попробуйте тест:

    ` // Ачивки здесь: $arrXml['playerAchievements']['achiev']

     echo "<pre>";

     print_r($arrXml['playerAchievements']['achiev']); 
      
     echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Для того, чтобы понять структуру, выведите

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrXml);
    echo "</pre>";

По отступам все будет видно.

Comment: @Magos уже разобрался, спасибо. Просто проморгал, проверял с разными XML и в некоторых нужные значения были равны 0